# Tracking same user based on different pages visit

Tags: javascript, php, networking

I have two shops on different domains. A user enters the shop A. How can I verify if the same user also entered shop B which is on different domain? I can't do this via cookies, because they are changing based on the domain. I tried to figure this out but I can't. I can't get the IP address because it will change dynamically in some time. I also can't track user by his MAC address because I would need to create a plugin and user would have to install it. I want to make it possible via JavaScript or PHP. Are there any solutions to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`HTTP_REFERER`** for this purpose.

Not sure which framework you are using but you must be having single entry point in your sub-domain where you can check HTTP_REFERER and see if it is coming from your main domain.

Using HTTP_REFERER **is not 100% trusted** as it can be altered but you can use it for some kind of reporting purpose to get some idea about your visitor.

If you need 100% working solution then you need to implement some kind of **router** which can manage both your domain and then you can write stuffs around.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can use ready-made solutions offered by Google Analytics for example (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id?hl=en). The other approach is build a user statistics collection service by yourself and both websites will use it (the service can use cookies). There is also number of other methods that does not involve cookies like ETags for example.